# Migration assistant unexpectedly quit

Tags: migration, migration-assistant

I am trying to transfer things from a Macbook Air to a Macbook Pro Retina. I start up Migration assistant on both and proceed with the initial steps, selecting the source laptop from the target Macbook Pro, then after around 10 seconds on the Macbook Pro I get a screen saying "Migration unexpectedly quit. Please try again."

The Macbook air seems oblivious of any issue and continues in a never ending loading stage. Both have all the updates installed. What can be the issue?

The migration is being done over Wi-Fi and the username and password for the user account is the same on both laptops. iCloud is not enabled on either. Not sure if any of those things are relevant.

Comment: what are the OS X differences ?

Comment: Both are on 10.10.4

Comment: Do you have to use WiFi? we are talking about Gigabytes of data.

Comment: You can't get fiber optic Wi-Fi, Wi-Fi is wireless networking, there are no cables, fiber optic refers to the internet connection to the internet from your Wi-Fi router.

Comment: I am using WiFi, Apple says that it's perfectly possible to do the migration this way, and I don't have a cable. https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204320

Comment: I bought a thunderbolt cable and still having the same issues, so frustrating!